# Cytoscape export network

Tags: proteins, visualization, network

I'm using Cytoscape to visualise a ppi network having 2000 proteins ... I m trying to export it but the supported format are only cytoscype formats not a usable ones 
and for the table format the network is separatted , I don't find it explorable .

How to I export that network in format convertable to csv . or csv so that I can use it in a tool supporting only csv  file format format

Comment: The SIF network format produces an edgelist. If you have attributes attached to nodes or edges then you'll need to export in xgmml, graphml or xml and then parse from there.